# Parse nested object in JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, string, parsing

I have this code:

```
let test = '{"attribute_as":"plan_id","operator":"fromTo","values":"{"from":"70","to":"80"}"}';
console.log(JSON.parse(test));
```

It of course fail because in `values` I have an object. Is there any option how to parse this string in easy way? Or is it not possible at all?

At the end the result should be:

```
{
    attribute_as: 'plan_id',
    operator: 'fromTo',
    values: {
        from: 70,
        to: 80
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this json string: `'{"attribute_as":"plan_id","operator":"fromTo","values":{"from":70,"to":80}}'`
I think the error was just a misplaced quotation mark

Comment: you have an error in key values, its string not an object, and you have to escape " inside value if you want a string, either you put off to have an object

Comment: Where are you getting the string from? If it's coming from a source you can control, the easiest way is to fix the string to real JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is incorrect:

```js
let err = '{"attribute_as":"plan_id","operator":"fromTo","values":"{"from":"70","to":"80"}"}';
// This is the original string
let pass = '{"attribute_as":"plan_id","operator":"fromTo","values":{"from":70,"to":80}}';
// Corrected string

let desiredObj = {
    attribute_as: 'plan_id',
    operator: 'fromTo',
    values: {
        from: 70,
        to: 80
    }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(desiredObj) == err);
console.log(JSON.stringify(desiredObj) == pass);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick. When logged both evaluated correctly.

```
let
    test = '{"attribute_as": "plan_id","operator": "fromTo","values": {"from": 70,"to": 80}}',
    test2 = {
        attribute_as: 'plan_id',
        operator: 'fromTo',
        values: {
            from: 70,
            to: 80
        }
    }

console.log(JSON.parse(test));
console.log(JSON.stringify(test2));
```